# Remove enumeration item from array PHP

Tags: php, enums

I have a database enum for payment methods e.g. credit card, cheque etc.

I have references this in code in multiple place, however in one instance i want to reference it but exclude one item in the list.

It's preferable to still reference this enum rather than manually add a new array, because if the enum itself ever changes I could have issues. While if I reference it with one item excluded: if the enum changes, so will this piece of code.

Currently I have:

```
public function PrepareInputs()
{
    parent::PrepareInputs();

    $this->AddInputs(
        $checkbox = new PgFormInputCheckBox2( "Prefulfilled" ),
        new PgFormInputSubmit( "Back", "Change Order", "start" ),
        **$paymentMethod = new PgFormInputSelect( "PaymentMethod", "", true ),**
        $submit = new PgFormInputSubmit( "PlaceOrder", "Place Order", "place", true )
    );
    $checkbox->printLabel = true;
    **$paymentMethod->enumeration = array("tblOrder.PaymentMethod");
    $paymentMethod->manualOptions = array( ":Please select" );**
}
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If it's one instance that you're wanting to behave differently, then localize the exception to that one instance.

So for example, on the rest of the site you iterate through your payment methods normally.  But, when you are dealing with your exception, iterate the array normally, but exclude during the loop.  Then if anything changes etc, it's only in one spot and the chance of breakage is almost non-existent and contained.

```
foreach($PaymentMethods as $k => $v){
    if($k !== 'SpecificMethodYouWantToExclude'){
         echo "$v":
    }
}
```